# Extra request to undefined when running React App

Tags: reactjs, request, react-router

I've got some strange "behavior" of my react app - actually when I start the app and check the requests, I have one extra request on undefined with a status code of 200.

[image]

I'm using create-react-app with React Router and the route to this specific page is dynamic like this:

`<Route exact path="/a/:link" component={MyComponent} />`

The `:link` is the dynamic part of the URL. As you can see, there's no error/failure and the response status code is 200, but it's extra request I don't want to make. Have you ever had a similar problem? Thank you, guys.

Comment: Hi what's in the response?

Comment: Hi, there's just index.html in the response (the content of the file) with empty div (root).